# How can i give instruction through XCM(Send message) function to send a message through parity-bridges-common?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, parity-bridges-common

Whenever i send one custom message provided by parity through this command

./target/debug/substrate-relay send-message millau-to-rialto 
--source-host localhost 
--source-port $MILLAU_PORT 
--source-signer //Alice 
raw 020419ac

It has been executing the three things
1: Xcmpallet.Sent
2: bridgeRialtoMessages.MessageAccepted
3: xcmPallet.FeesPaid

But how can i send a message through the XCM instruction from explorer only rather than from terminal . Can someone please guide me through this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This the encoded bytes for sending trap instruction:

> 0x6300010100030419e5c0

**Explanation**:

```
dest: XcmVersionedMultiLocation = V3 (version 3) {
    parent :u8 => 1 (going one level up and pointing to relaychain)
    interior: XcmV3Junctions => Here (we want to execute the instruction in relaychain)
}

message: XcmVersionedXcm : V3 (version 3) {
    0: XcmV3Instruction: XcmV3Instruction => Trap (XCM instruction)
    Trap: Compact<u64>: 1234 (user defined value to trap)
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Then how i can give instruction to transfer assets from one chain to another chain ? Can you please tell ? It is showing unreachable

Comment: Unfortunately, parity-common-bridges repo is not configured to perform this operation for now. You need to configure it in order to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Teleportation [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/bin/millau/runtime/src/xcm_config.rs#L125). in your code